# Android Compound Controls affecting each other

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-controls

I am having problems using multiple versions of a compound control I have created. When I use it twice in the same `Fragment`, any text I enter in the `EditText` field of the 1st control is replaced by the text I entered in the `EditText` of the 2nd control after device rotation. The 2 versions of my control seem to be affecting each other.

My compound control extends a `LinearLayout` and is as follows:

```
public class MyCompoundControl extends LinearLayout {

    public MyCompoundControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_my_compound_control, this, true);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyControlViewOptions);
        String value1 = a.getString(R.styleable.MyControlViewOptions_firstvalue);
        String value2 = a.getString(R.styleable.MyControlViewOptions_secondvalue);
        a.recycle();

        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_label_1);
        EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_label_2);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_label_1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_label_2);

        textView1.setText(value1);
        textView2.setText(value2);
    }
}
```

Below is my **layout.xml** file for the compound control which uses a merge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_label_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_label_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_label_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_label_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </merge>
```

Then I use this control 2x in my **fragment layout**:

```
xmlns:mycustom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    ...

    <com.android.mytracker.custom.MyCompoundControl
        android:id="@+id/control_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        mycustom:firstvalue="weight1"
        mycustom:secondvalue="weight2" />

    <com.android.mytracker.custom.MyCompoundControl
        android:id="@+id/control_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        mycustom:firstvalue="height1"
        mycustom:secondvalue="height2" />
```

Then if I type in text in `EditText` (`edittext_label_1`) in `control_1` and type in text in `EditText` (`edittext_label_1`) in `control_2`. Then when I rotate my device, the text I entered in `control_2` is now displayed in both `control_1` and control_2`.

It's definitely not my code doing this. If I then switch the order of my compound controls in the **fragment layout** above (e.g. `control_2` then `control_1`), then it switches. The control I put first in my **fragment layout** always has its `EditText` value overwritten by the control that comes after it when I rotate the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was an identical problem. Solved perfectly with the selected answer in the link below:

[Android:  embedded controls in multiply included compound control restore to same state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379271/android-embedded-controls-in-multiply-included-compound-control-restore-to-sam)